# Function that takes in X and return all sets for #t/#f

Tags: scheme

So ive been sitting here thinking of how to do this and im quite stuck,
i want it to work like

```
(Return_Set 2)  returns=> ((#t, #t) (#t, #f) (#f, #t) (#f, #f))
(Return_Set 1)  returns=> ((#t) (#f))
(define (Return_Set N)
```

I know for `(/ (expt 2 N) 2)` i need to put all `#t` then append it to:

```
(Return_Set N-1)
```

and do the same for #f but from there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: write a procedure that returns the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between an arbitrary number of lists (hint: you'll find the algorithm by googling!). Then you'll be able to solve this problem easily, like this:

```
(return-set 1) ; is equivalent to (cartesian-product '(#t #f))
=> '((#t #f))

(return-set 2) ; is equivalent to (cartesian-product '(#t #f) '(#t #f))
=> '((#t #t) (#t #f) (#f #t) (#f #f))

(return-set 3) ; is equivalent to (cartesian-product '(#t #f) '(#t #f) '(#t #f))
=> '((#t #t #t) (#t #t #f) (#t #f #t) (#t #f #f)
     (#f #t #t) (#f #t #f) (#f #f #t) (#f #f #f))
```

To make things easier, also write a procedure that builds a new list repeating a value `n` times. Now the solution to the problem can be easily expressed like this:

```
(define (cartesian-product . lsts)
  <???>) ; ToDo

(define (repeat element n)
  <???>) ; ToDo

(define (return-set n)
  (apply cartesian-product
         (repeat '(#t #f) n)))
```

I can give you a hand with the above procedures, but first let's see what have you tried so far, and I mean: a real effort with working code, in Stack Overflow it's frowned upon to spoon-feed answers to homeworks.

**UPDATE:**

Oh, well. @GoZoner gave a straight answer to OP's homework, so it doesn't make much sense to withhold my answer now. Here's a possible solution using Racket:

```
(define (cartesian-product . lsts)
  (foldr (lambda (lst acc)
           (for*/list ((x (in-list lst))
                       (y (in-list acc)))
             (cons x y)))
         '(())
         lsts))

(define (repeat elt n)
  (build-list n (const elt)))

(define (return-set n)
  (apply cartesian-product
         (repeat '(#t #f) n)))
```

Comment: Sorry, now that the #homework tag is gone, no reason to hold back.

Comment: @GoZoner I disagree. When a question is clearly a homework, and the OP isn't showing any effort to solve it, you're not doing any good by spoon-feeding the answer, it's plain wrong.

Comment: But if he is actually cheating; he'll get called out eventually in his life.  I'm just thankful people are asking Scheme question.  And, I'm wondering how you get to each Scheme question first!

Comment: @GoZoner by hitting the refresh button every 5 minutes :P

Comment: thanks so much!! it is hw but its only a small part of it i kinda wanted to do it the hard way, if it makes you feel better you only gave me 20% of my hw thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This gets it done:

```
(define (return-set n)
  (define (cons-of x)
    (lambda (l) (cons x l)))
  (assert (positive? n))
  (if (= n 1)
      '((#t) (#f))
      (let ((n_1 (return-set (- n 1))))
        (append (map (cons-of #f) n_1)
                (map (cons-of #t) n_1)))))
```

The key insight it to recognize that the result for N is simply built on the result of N-1.